# How to read all data from abstract Shared Object file? (Flash, Actionscript)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml, shared-objects

what I meen is to get all objects and their properties, is it possible? How to do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read the SharedObject. The [documentation](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#includeExamplesSummary) is a great start.
2. Loop through the properties. Depending on how you stored them if they are simple, a **for...in** loop should do it. If you are storing complex types (like an Object inside and Object, etc.), you need to first check if the object is simple or not. If it is not, you need to loop through its properties.

Luckily, since you've tagged this for flex as well, the [ObjectUtils](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html) class will be handy for things like checking if an Object [isSimple()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html#isSimple()) or inspecting an Object's properties via [getClassInfo()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html#getClassInfo()).

```
e.g.
//assuming nestedObjectFromSO is a nested object read from a SharedObject
trace(ObjectUtil.getClassInfo(nestedObjectFromSO).properties);
```

Depending on your structure, you might need to write a recursive function that gets the data from nested objects within your SharedObject.

HTH,
George

Comment: the next question is how t actually open SOfrom abstractfile?

Comment: 1. Next question wasn't post it yet ;) One thing at a time, right ?
2. I don't know what you mean b 'SOfrom abstractfile'. What's an abstractfile ?

Comment: @Ole Jak so this one is answered ? :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AIR Shared Object Editor](http://blog.coursevector.com/minerva) to grab and edit .sol files.